# interactive console for Ruby, PHP

Tags: php, ruby

How do you start the Interactive Console for ruby and php

Answer (score 96):

For ruby, you want the '`irb`' command.

For python, you can enter interactive mode with the '`python`' command.

For php, you enter a basic interactive mode with '`php -a`'.  Because of its limitations, other interactive shells have sprung up.  [PHP-Shell](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/php-shell/) is one of them.

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you are working with a Ruby On Rails project you could use

```
ruby script/console
```

from your Rails application root. This is a good approach since you get an interactive ruby shell and the advantage is that loads the entire application stack for you. Pretty handy if you are testing your new code or trying to debug something.

Comment: `ruby script/rails console`      
(rails version > 3)

Answer (score 2):

php doesn't lend itself very well to an interactive shell, because you can't redefine functions and classes. So while [there *is*](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/php-shell) an interactive shell available, it's not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have php5-cli installed and type 'php -a' at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [phpsh](http://www.phpsh.org/) same as irb for ruby. php-cli allow you to run scripts for the command line like

```
myserver> php -r "echo 'hola mundo';"
```

so what you are asking and all replies about php-cli are different. also php-cli has it own php.ini that allow you to have differents configurations depends of run php over httpd (like apache) or in bash

saludos

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent script for PHP that allows you to run a php console on a local website.

http://seld.be/notes/php-console-in-your-browser

There's obvious security implications here, but if it's only accessible locally, then there's no need to worry.

Really saves time if you want to double check the function behaviour, or to isolate a piece of code and diagnose what happens.

Answer (score 1):

For a console with a rails 3.x+ project loaded

```
rails c
```

this is shorthand for `ruby scripts/rails console`

See more abbreviations here: http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/abkuerzungen.html

Answer (score 0):

In php its php or php-cli - different name in different installations